# Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to Collection<? extends Object>

Tags: java, collections, warnings, unchecked-conversion

I'm using set for defining allowed keys for some action. Eclipse shows this warning:

```
 Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion
 to conform to Collection<? extends Object>
```

I googled a bit and found same message in slightly different cases but its probably similar problem.  
Is any chance get rid of this warning other way then

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Is good idea to use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

in this case?

Here is my code:

```
  public static final String KEY_A = "A_VALUE";
  public static final String KEY_B = "B_VALUE";

  public static final Set<?> allowedKeys =  new HashSet<Object>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {KEY_A, KEY_B}));
```

Comment: Why not use `Set<String>` and `HashSet<String>`?

Comment: @Eran I think it really doesn't matter which type is it. I only call on it 
allowedKeys.contains(key).
Or there is any useful difference between it?
By the way if you write it like you asked, the situation with the warning message is still the same.

Comment: Which expression _exactly_ does your error relate to? You haven't shown any place where you convert from the raw type `List` to `Collection<?>`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik All code related is mentioned in question. Only other action is mentioned my previous comment allowedKeys.contains(key) which is used for checking if the key is in the Set its all. But I found the cause already. Autoimport in eclipce did the mess. Instead of java.util.Arrays it taken import edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays;
Its just one of that WTF cases it happens when IDE tries to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse did the mess: 
Wrong:

```
import edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays;
```

Correct:

```
import jave.util.Arrays;
```

So code is ok both versions `Set<?>` and `Set<String>`. Eclipse just auto imported bad class.

Answer (score 3):

The `Set<?>` or `Set<Object>` should only be used in case you must make it works with existing code. Otherwise, trying to make a specific type instead.

If you are sure that the set contains only `String` element, `Set<String>` is the best choice.

Comment: +1 For explanation the Set<?> and Set<Object>, I'm making it works with existing code, but I'm pretty sure it will be always Strings so I'm moving to Set<?>

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the problem using source code and get rid of type unchecked conversion warnings,

```
private static Vector<Vector<String>> tableVectorData;
private static Vector<String> rowData = new Vector<String>();
```

for adding element -

```
rowData.clear();
rowData.addElement((strings[0])[0][0]);
rowData.addElement((strings[0])[1][0]);
tableVectorData.addElement(rowData);
```

for retrieving element -

```
model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
rowCount = tableVectorData.size();
int i = 0;
while(i < rowCount) {
    Vector<String> row = tableVectorData.get(i++);//here the type check warning will occur
    model.setRowCount(model.getRowCount()+1);
    System.out.println(row);
    model.setValueAt(row.get(0), model.getRowCount()-1, 0);
    model.setValueAt(row.get(1), model.getRowCount()-1, 1);
}
```

or using `Iterator<Vector<String>>` -

```
Iterator<Vector<String>> rows = tableVectorData.iterator();//here the type check warning will occur
boolean flag = false;

checkValue:
while(rows.hasNext()) {
    Vector<String> vect = rows.next();
    if(vect.contains(value)) {
        flag = true;
        break checkValue;
    }
}
```

Hope these will provide you a way to deal with these expression type check warnings, thanks.